# How to connect Kentico to Azure SQL database using managed identity

Tags: kentico, azure-managed-identity, kentico-13

I am using Kentico 13 and trying to connect to the Azure SQL database using managed identity in my localhost environment using the below connection string.

```
"Server=tcp:<MyServer>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<MyDB>;Authentication=Active Directory Device Code Flow;"
```

I am getting the below error

```
CMS.DataEngine.ApplicationInitException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.'
```

How can I get past this error or is there any other way to connect to the database using managed Identity?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a way to customize creating the database context in Kentico.

https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/customizing-providers/custom-data-provider-example

I followed the steps mentioned in the above article and then modified the `DataConnection` class, `CreateNativeConnection` method as below

```
protected override IDbConnection CreateNativeConnection()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    var credential = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential();
    var token = credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net//.default" }),default);
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try searching on Google or MSDN pages as this is more related to Azure SQL and not Kentico. E.g. I found this: [Tutorial: Use a Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql)
or [Managed identities in Azure AD for Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity?view=azuresql) and as it looks like, you need to use Azure AD. Local identities are probably not supported. I would maybe ask Azure SQL support.

Comment: The logic to create Database Context resides within Kentico dlls and I can't do much (I guess) to overwrite that code. I believe the issue is with Kentico rather than Azure

Comment: So, how do you connect in non Kentico project?